# when scale the application in cloud foundry then fetch multiple time the same record from one database and write multiple in other database

Tags: java, microservices

I have one application to fetch data from one database and write to other database. when i scale the instance of application then fetch the same record in multiple and write multiple times in database.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should add more details to your question: How is the program, how are you doing the scaling (through multithreading, through multi-instancing, etc), how is the query recovering the input records, etc. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: So is  your expected behavior ?